# There is any limits for the usage of Android Google maps API?

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

I'm developing android application which is intended to just display maps. Can i display unlimited maps without usage limits on moblie apps? which version of maps API? i make some search  about other alternatives such as openstreetmap but i found that the complexity of utilzation's more high. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. they do have. Go the FAQ https://developers.google.com/maps/faq